# CSS in the head is showing up on the page

Tags: html, css

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    .green {
    color: green;
    font-size: 2em;
    }
</head>
```

This is my entire `head`, the

```css
.green {
color: green;
font-size: 2em;
}
```

Is showing up at the top of the webpage.

I have Googled this but cannot find a fix, apparently only things in the `body` should show up on the page.

Anyone know how to fix?

Comment: I would advise placing all css into a css style sheet - makes it much easier to edit/update in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to place styling within your HTML document, you need to wrap it within a [`style` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style):

```
<head>
    ...
    <style type="text/css">
        .green {
            color: green;
            font-size: 2em;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

Depending on what you're trying to do, however, you could just add this to your existing `css.css` file which your `link` element includes on your page.

Answer (score 0):

Add **style** tag to it

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
       <style>
          .green 
   {
          color: green;
          font-size: 2em;
    }
       </style>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

you linked yourpage to a css.css file
you either add your css code into that file, or you add the `<style></style>` to wrap your code so that it would be processed as style